# Insert Multiple value when if condition return true

Tags: mysql, case

Insert Multiple value in table  When If condition  return true . if condition checks two table data and return true and false accordingly.

structure-

```
products: id, qty_on_hand
orders: id, product_id, qty ,price,room_number etc
roomTable :id,product_id,room_number,booked_status
```

insert all data in orders table when requested total qty is less then qty_on_hand

please tell how case statement is used in this .thanks in advance

Comment: no data comes from user end where id is primary key in all tables. I jus want to check if quatity left then book order other wise return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO orders (id, product_id, qty ,price,room_number, etc)
SELECT $id, $product_id, $qty, $price, $room_number, ...
FROM products
WHERE id = $id AND $qty < qty_on_hand;
```

Replace all the `$xxx` with the data you want to insert.

Comment: where is $xxx in your query

Comment: I meant $id, $product_id, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything in the previous query is rite except the "id" part and a possible missing join on roomtable
i think the product_id is the id requested..
also there needs to be an inner join on roomTable to get the ... data

My intution is that the id column in orders table is autogenerated

```
INSERT INTO orders (product_id, qty ,price,room_number, etc)
SELECT products.id, products.qty, products.price, roomTable.room_number, ...
FROM products
Inner join roomTable
on roomtable.product_id = products.id
WHERE products.id = $id AND $qty < qty_on_hand;
```

i wud assume the code to be::

```
    begin tran orderstransaction
     //This will insert a new order with an autogenerated order id..    
      INSERT INTO orders (product_id, qty ,price,room_number, etc)
        SELECT products.id, products.qty, products.price, roomTable.room_number, ...
        FROM products
        Inner join roomTable
        on roomtable.product_id = products.id
        WHERE products.id = $id AND $qty < qty_on_hand;

    //this will reduce the qty_on_hand by $qty now that an order has been posted 
    update products set qty_on_hand = (qty_on_hand - $qty)
    where products.id = $id

    commit tran orderstransaction
```

Here is my EDIT with at least one statement that will work

```
SQL Insert Statement that worked for me
..................
this sql statement below assumes that id in orders is not autogenerated..
i did not see an attribute for price in products so hardcoded it to 2500 to be replaced with products.price assuming there is a price in products table.
Now assuming that u r querying for product_id=1 and qty=250 which are ur inputs for the query, am inserting order id 10000 into orders
INSERT INTO orders (id,product_id, qty ,price,room_number)
        SELECT 10000,products.id,250 , 2500, roomTable.room_number
        FROM products
        Inner join roomTable
        on roomtable.product_id = products.id
        WHERE products.id = 1 AND 250 < products.qty_on_hand
..........................................................
This Sql assumes order id is autogenerated
  INSERT INTO orders (product_id, qty ,price,room_number)
        SELECT products.id,250 , 2500, roomTable.room_number
        FROM products
        Inner join roomTable
        on roomtable.product_id = products.id
        WHERE products.id = 1 AND 250 < products.qty_on_hand
........................................................
```

Comment: getting following error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tran orderstransaction
    
      INSERT INTO orders (product_id, qty ,price,' at line 1

Comment: well added a working statement replacing the hardcoded variable values with numerical values.. these numerical values that were substituted would either come as inputs to a stored procedure or wud be collected by the user in a form.. products.id and order_qty are basically the inputs im talking abt.. i cud not find the price attribute which i think must be in products but not mentioned. cheers